# Symbols to samples at the transmitter and samples to symbols at the receiver

Tags: digital-communications, sampling, detection

Suppose I have the $N\times 1$ vector $\mathbf{x}$ that contains binary phase shift keying (BPSK) symbols each with power $P_s$ Watts.

- At the transmitter: I want to convert these symbols into samples using rectangular pulse shaping, where each symbol is repeated $J$ times. My question for this part is: the symbol power should be divided to all the samples, such that each sample will have a power of $P_s/J$ Watts, or equivalently, the SNR per sample is $1/J$ the SNR per symbol, right? In MATLAB, and over a noise-limited AWGN channel this would be

  ```
   SNR = 10; % SNR per symbol in linear scale
   J = 10; % # of samples per symbol
   N = 10^5; % # number of symbols
   x = 2.*(rand(N,1) > 0.5) - 1; % This generate BPSK symbols +1, -1
   s = repelem(x, J); % repeat each symbol J times because it's rectangular pulse shaping
   n = sqrt(J/SNR).*randn(N,1); % generate Gaussian noise with variance J/SNR
   r = s + n; % the received samples, where the SNR per sample is SNR/J
  ```
- At the receiver: having the received samples $\mathbf{r}$, how can I recover the symbols $\mathbf{x}$?